# How to limit string in laravel 5.4 from specific char?

Tags: php, string, laravel

I create search option, with autocomplete. So when I search some string it shows the result automatic and also color the string searched in the result.

I used str_limit() function to limit my long text, but if the searched string is longer then the limit I gave I don't see what I have search.

Is there any way to start the limit from specific char?

Here is my code:

Blade file that shows the results:

```
<style>
   .color_str_search {
       color: #ff0000;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
   }
</style>

<ul id="searchResults">
   @foreach($titles as $title) 
    <li onClick="selectTitle('{{ $title->name}}');">
        <div class="title">{{  $title->name }}</div>
        <div class="desc">{!!  str_limit(str_replace($str,"<span 
         class='color_str_search'>$str</span>",$title->notes), 110,'...') !!}
        </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use substr() function in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use strpos to locate the position and substr to get substring

```
<?php 
$str = "I love php";
$position = strpos($str,"p");
$sub_str = substr($str,$position,$limit);
echo $sub_str;
?>
```

Answer would look like "ph"

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr() which is a php function

```
substr($str, start_from, length);
```

start_from - Start at a specified position in the string. start_from is a number. The first letter from the string start with 0.

length - The length to be returned from the start parameter

Example : `substr($str, 0, 10);`